# How do I turn an Integer into an Int in Haskell

Tags: haskell, integer, int

I want to turn an Integer into an Int so it agrees with my type declaration. There must be a simple way of doing this like casting in Java?

Comment: You don't "turn" objects of one type into another one, at best you _convert_ between types. But in Haskell, it's generally preferred to simply work with the required type right from the beginning; thanks to polymorphic return types etc. this often works without even thinking about it. In ghci, you might just use `let x = 5 :: Int` if you previously had `let x = 5` (which BTW is only `Integer` because of the [dreaded monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction). If you `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction`, everything may work a charm without conversions).

Answer (score 4):

Just use the `fromInteger` function:

```
fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a
```

You'd use it in GHCi like

```
> fromInteger (1 :: Integer) :: Int
1
```

But beware that there's some interesting behavior if you go beyond the bounds of an `Int`:

```
> let x = (fromIntegral (maxBound :: Int) :: Integer) + 1
> x
2147483648
> fromInteger x :: Int
-2147483648
```

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that an `Integer` could have a value that is much larger than what fits in an `Int`, so you would get an overflow when doing the conversion in some cases.

However, with that precaution out of the way, the easiest way to do the conversion is to simply use the `fromIntegral` function:

```
myInteger :: Integer
myInteger = 1234

myInt :: Int
myInt = fromIntegral myInteger
```